# select in where - Linq Query

Tags: linq

I have two tables `tbl_role_master` and `tbl_user_master`.

`tbl_role_master` has the below values

```
role_id   role    rolevalue
1         admin     1
2         gen       2
3         test1     4
4         test2     8
5         test3     16
```

`rolevalue` contains fibonacciseries..
`tbl_user_master` contains the below values

```
user_id   user_name  rolevlue_consolidated
1         user1       15
2         user2        3
3         user3        7
```

`rolevlue_consolidated` contains the addition of combination of `rolevalue` in `tbl_role_master` table
for ex: user1's 15 has the roles of admin,gen,test1 and test2

now i want a linq query to get the roles from tbl_role_master based on user_id in `tbl_user_master`

for ex if i passs `user_id` 2 the select query should return

```
admin
gen
```

i have sql query -

```
select 
    role 
from 
    tbl_rol_master 
WHERE (
    select 
        rolevalue_consolidated 
    from 
        tbl_user_master 
    where 
        User_Id=" + userId + "
)
```

Comment: The sql query is also not valid: `... WHERE (SELECT...)`. You have to specify the search-condition.

Comment: but sql query working fine..

Comment: Maybe you have not posted the real query. I assume you have forgotten to specify the `IN`-clause: `WHERE SomeColumn IN (SELECT rolevalue_consolidated ...)`

Comment: This query actually do the fibonacci series logic.but i dont know how to implement in linq.hope you understand..pls help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two lists, one with all the roles and one with all your users you can do something like this:

```
var userRoles = roles.Where(role => (role.RoleValue & 
                    users.First(user => user.Id == YourUserId) == role.RoleValue);
```

Which returns you a list with all assigned rights of the user with the given user id.